# Deactivate map's 'on' listener in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, point, angular

Is there a way to deactivate simple `on` listener? I want to create some Points on the map, only if a dialog is opened and do that until user hits the 'Calculate Route' button. Once one of those two options is handled I don't need it anymore.

```typescript
map.on('click', (event: MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>) => {
  this.updateCoordinates(event.coordinate);
});

// I was hoping to get some reference and dispose it
this.onRef = map.on('click', (event: MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>) => {
  this.updateCoordinates(event.coordinate);
});

// Something like that, but dispose doesn't exist for this object.
this.onRef.dispose();
```

Or should I rather use `Select` object for this? Which I know how to dispose on demand.

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Observable.html#.unByKey `unByKey(this.onRef)`

Comment: Well that's an obfuscated functionality! But thanks, it works as expected.